# Login doesn't show up in Gatsby using Auth0, withAuthenticationRequired

Tags: routes, gatsby, auth0

I'm using Gatsby with auth0, and when I wrap a page with `withAuthenticationRequired`, then I get a blank page that says "Redirecting..."

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { withAuthenticationRequired } from '@auth0/auth0-react';


const UserIndexPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      User index page
    </div>
  );
};

export default withAuthenticationRequired(UserIndexPage, {
  onRedirecting: () => <div>Redirecting...</div>
});
```

The login screen doesn't come up, and the page is stuck with that Redirecting message

If I create a login button, without `withAuthenticationRequired` then the login screen comes up when I click it

```
const LoginButton = () => {
  const { loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0();
  return <button onClick={() => loginWithRedirect()}>Log In</button>;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reviewing the new implementation released I believe the onRedirect callback should be managed by the Gatsby Browser (`gatsby-browser.js`):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Auth0Provider } from '@auth0/auth0-react';
import { navigate } from 'gatsby';

const onRedirectCallback = (appState) => {
  navigate(appState?.returnTo || '/', { replace: true });
};

export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  return (
    <Auth0Provider
      domain="YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN"
      clientId="YOUR_AUTH0_CLIENT_ID"
      redirectUri={window.location.origin}
      onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
    >
      {element}
    </Auth0Provider>
  );
};
```

While in your UI view:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { withAuthenticationRequired } from '@auth0/auth0-react';


const UserIndexPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      User index page
    </div>
  );
};

export default withAuthenticationRequired(UserIndexPage);
```

The idea is to wrap the component in the `withAuthenticationRequired` handler.

The `onRedirectCallback` will use Gatsby's `navigate` function to return the user to the protected route after the login and will replace the URL to avoid odd behavior when the user's trying to move forward and backward.

Comment: I should've included details about how I had already wrapped with Auth0Provider.  I just thought that it was implied when I mentioned that authentication works without `withAuthenticationRequired`.  After working on this, now I am able to bring up the login screen after changing some settings in auth0 admin screen, more detail about that are mentioned in this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69770122/experiencing-redirect-loop-with-a-protected-route-in-gatsby-using-auth0?noredirect=1#comment123330494_69770122

Comment: Since the login page does show up I'll just accept this as the answer and close it, I don't think this question needs to be answered further.  Thanks for the help!