# Experiencing redirect loop with a protected route in Gatsby using Auth0

Tags: redirect, gatsby, auth0

Note: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69703103/login-doesnt-show-up-in-gatsby-using-auth0-withauthenticationrequired) is not a duplicate, I'm not sure why anyone is thinking that...

---

I’m having issue with implementing protected pages(routes) in Gatsby with Auth0

Currently, when I point the browser to `localhost:8000/user/protectedpage`, it goes to the login screen, and after a successful login, it comes back to that route, and the browser seems to be stuck on a loop loading between two routes.

When I tested with this, the page was doing a indefinite redirect loop while showing "Redirect..." on the page:

```
export default withAuthenticationRequired(ProtectedPage, {
  onRedirecting: () => <div>Redirecting...</div>
});
```

`redirectUri` in Auth0Provider is set to `redirectUri={window.location.origin + '/user'}`

Allowed Callback URLs in the auth0 admin page, is set to, `http://localhost:8000/user`

If I change these routes to `window.location.origin` and `http://localhost:8000/`, then after a successful login, it’ll redirect to that page and stay there.

I need it to redirect to where it was trying to go to instead.
As in, if I navigate to `localhost:8000/user/protectedpage`, then after logging in, it should redirect to that route and load that page successfully, instead of being stuck in a loop like mentioned earlier.

Here are some codes:

```
// File structure
src
  > pages
       > user
          > index.js
          > protectedpage
       index.js
  gatsby-browser.js
```

```
// gatsby-browser.js
import React from 'react';
import { Auth0Provider } from '@auth0/auth0-react';
import { navigate } from 'gatsby';

const onRedirectCallback = (appState) => {
  navigate(appState?.returnTo || '/', { replace: true });
};

export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  return (
    <Auth0Provider
      domain={process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}
      clientId={process.env.AUTH0_CLIENTID}
      redirectUri={window.location.origin + '/user'}
      onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
    >
      {element}
    </Auth0Provider>
  );
};
```

```
// protectedpage.js
import React from 'react';
import { withAuthenticationRequired } from '@auth0/auth0-react';

const ProtectedPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      Protected Page
    </div>
  );
};

export default withAuthenticationRequired(ProtectedPage);
```

```
// auth0 Application URIs

Allowed Callback URLs
http://localhost:8000/user
```

Comment: @FerranBuireu Hi, sorry about that, I wasn't ignoring your response, I just felt that it hasn't fully answered my question yet, e.g. I mentioned that I used `withAuthenticationRequired`, and your answer was recommending that.  I wanted to extend the original question, but felt that with more details and with a new problem now it should be a new question, which is the infinite redirect loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Login doesn't show up in Gatsby using Auth0, withAuthenticationRequired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69703103/login-doesnt-show-up-in-gatsby-using-auth0-withauthenticationrequired)

Comment: @DanielWiddis That question was asked by me, and this question adds more detail to that.  It looks like after logging in, the url that it redirects to redirects back to log in page which redirects to that page, and back and forth... and it gets stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your full implementation but to me, the fact that it gets stuck in an infinite loop could be related to the fact that you are replacing the history by removing the last visited page in:

```
  navigate(appState?.returnTo || '/', { replace: true });
```

In addition, the callback is receiving an `appState` otherwise, it makes the history replacing but you are never providing it at (`onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}`):

```
// gatsby-browser.js
import React from 'react';
import { Auth0Provider } from '@auth0/auth0-react';
import { navigate } from 'gatsby';

const onRedirectCallback = (appState) => {
  navigate(appState?.returnTo || '/', { replace: true });
};

export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  return (
    <Auth0Provider
      domain={process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN}
      clientId={process.env.AUTH0_CLIENTID}
      redirectUri={window.location.origin + '/user'}
      onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback} //<-- here you are not providing an appState
    >
      {element}
    </Auth0Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by that I'm not providing an appState? Isn't appState a parameter passed to the function `onRedirectCallback`?  Is the issue with this? `appState?.returnTo`

Comment: I am not testing your application and I don't have a sandbox to test how it behaves. I'm providing feedback based on the few snippets provided. My guess, seeing the code is that the `appState` will be always `null` (because it's not provided) so it will enter the else condition which is replacing the history state, possibly creating the loop you mention. Test it to print its value to discard this theory

Comment: Hmm, I just tested with `onRedirectCallback={window.location.origin + '/user'}` and by commenting it out completely (so that no onRedirectCallback is specified), and they both result in the same redirect loop after the signup.

Comment: Also, changing redirectUri to `redirectUri={window.location.origin + '/user/protected'}`, so that it's pointing to the actual `/protected` page,  leads to the same redirect loop error as well

with this update in the auth0 admin page
`Allowed Callback URLs: http://localhost:8000, http://localhost:8000/user, http://localhost:8000/user/protected`

Comment: So maybe the issue is in the view component. Can you provide a sandbox?

Comment: I wasn't able to get the log in screen to show up on codesandbox, so here's the GitHub repo instead

Comment: https://github.com/jsphkm/gatsby-auth0-test2.git